# Cannot Hide and Show Particular Sheet on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have this code assigned to a command button (on sheet 5). My goal is when the command button is clicked, sheet 4 will be shown and other sheets will be hidden. But unfortunately when i run the code, it shows error:

Run time error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error

Any idea how to solve this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Sheet1.Visible = False
    Sheet2.Visible = False
    Sheet3.Visible = False
    Sheet4.Visible = True
    Sheet5.Visible = False
    Sheet6.Visible = False
    Sheet7.Visible = False
    Sheet8.Visible = False
    Sheet4.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: The error doesnt show which line, just a pop up warning

Comment: no "Debug" button?  Is this the only code in the workbook?

Comment: Yes, there is no debug button. There are more code but the rest works fine

Comment: Is your VB project locked?

Comment: No, it isnt locked

Comment: There must be at least one visible sheet, so try moving the Sheet4.Visible line to the top.

Comment: Yes i tried it and it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

Answer (score 0):

would you try?

```
Sheets(1).visible = false
Sheets(2).visible = false
sheets(3).visible = false
sheets(4).visible = true
Sheets(5).visible = false
Sheets(6).visible = false
sheets(7).visible = false
sheets(8).visible = false
sheets(4).activate
```